# Removing XML Node In PowerShell Removes Extra Tags That I Need

Tags: xml, powershell, tags, removechild

I have an XML file in the following format:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<factory>
  <map>
    <add key="Audit" assembly="Python.Platform.Core.dll" class="Python.Core.Audit.Services.Audit">
      <parameter name="configFilePath" class="string" value="Config\Audit\AuditConfiguration.xml" />
    </add>
    <add key="Security.Password" assembly="OpenContent.Platform.Core.dll" class="OpenContent.Core.Security.Services.PasswordSecurityMD5">
    </add>
    <add key="Security.Password.Local" assembly="OpenContent.Platform.Core.dll" class="OpenContent.Core.Security.Services.PasswordSecurityMD5">
    </add>
    <add key="Guest.Registration" assembly="OpenContent.Platform.Core.dll" class="OpenContent.Core.Guest.Services.DbGuestRegistration">
      <parameter name="registrationStoredProcedure" class="string" value="AddNewGuest" />
      <parameter name="updateEncodedKeyStoredProcedure" class="string" value="UpdateGuestEncodedKey" />
      <parameter name="unregistrationStoredProcedure" class="string" value="DeleteGuest" />
      <parameter name="DeleteExpiredGuestStoredProcedure" class="string" value="DeleteExpiredGuest" />
      <parameter name="defaultValidDays" class="int" value="30" />
    </add>
  </map>
</factory>
```

My goal is to remove this section:

```xml
    <add key="Audit" assembly="Python.Platform.Core.dll" class="Python.Core.Audit.Services.Audit">
      <parameter name="configFilePath" class="string" value="Config\Audit\AuditConfiguration.xml" />
    </add>
```

The PowerShell Script I'm running is as follows:

```xml
$path = "C:\testing\myxml.xml"

[Xml]$myxml = Get-Content -Path $path -Raw

$old = $myxml.SelectSingleNode("/factory/map/add[@key='Audit']")

$parent = $old.ParentNode
[void] $parent.RemoveChild($old)

$myxml.save($path)
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, it's also removing any closing tag  from any Add node that does not have a paramet child node.  So instead of just deleting the section I want to delete (which it is doing), it now looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<factory>
  <map>



    <add key="Security.Password" assembly="OpenContent.Platform.Core.dll" class="OpenContent.Core.Security.Services.PasswordSecurityMD5">

    <add key="Security.Password.Local" assembly="OpenContent.Platform.Core.dll" class="OpenContent.Core.Security.Services.PasswordSecurityMD5">

    <add key="Guest.Registration" assembly="OpenContent.Platform.Core.dll" class="OpenContent.Core.Guest.Services.DbGuestRegistration">
      <parameter name="registrationStoredProcedure" class="string" value="AddNewGuest" />
      <parameter name="updateEncodedKeyStoredProcedure" class="string" value="UpdateGuestEncodedKey" />
      <parameter name="unregistrationStoredProcedure" class="string" value="DeleteGuest" />
      <parameter name="DeleteExpiredGuestStoredProcedure" class="string" value="DeleteExpiredGuest" />
      <parameter name="defaultValidDays" class="int" value="30" />
    </add>
  </map>
</factory>
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to run without removing the extra  closing tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the default behavior of `XmlElement.WriteTo()` and similar methods - using shortform tags for any leaf elements that have no inner non-xml content.

The way this is determined is by [inspecting the `IsEmpty` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.isempty(v=vs.110).aspx) of each element, so you can trick a writer into preserving longform tags by setting `IsEmpty` to `$false` before calling `Save()`:

```
# Locate all <add /> nodes with no child elements
$addLeafNodes = $myxml.SelectNodes('//add[not(child::*)]')

# Loop through them
foreach($node in $AddLeafNodes){
    # Set IsEmpty property to false
    $node.IsEmpty = $false
}

# Save document
$myxml.Save($path)
```

Comment: Hm... that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Upon further investigation, I don't think there ever was an issue... I had started by making a backup copy of the file called myxml.xml.original.  After I made the changes I compared myxml.xml.original to myxml.xml... Apparently it's CompareIt that didn't like that line... When I look in the file the tags are definitely there, but CompareIt apparently doesn't like xml files.

Comment: @ChristopherCass Might be because of differences in whitespace then